# How do I find the local max And min

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on this question and have no idea how to find the local max and min of $$\int_a^x \frac{t^2+2t-24}{1+\cos^{2}t}, dt$$ I'm not sure where to start with this one since the integral doesn't have an exact boundary.

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, perhaps? It tells you what the derivative of the integral is as a function of $x.$

Comment: If $f$ has a local maxima (/minima) at an interior point, what do you know about $f'$?

Comment: As Chris comments, the derivative will be $0$., which occurs where the quadratic is $0$. Now which is max and min, you can decide by the coefficient of the $t^2$ term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) which says

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left\{\int_{a}^{t} f(\tau)d\tau\right\} = f'(t)$$

For us this means $$f'(x) = \frac{x^2+2x - 24}{\cos(x)^2+1}$$

The denominator is $\geq 1$ always, so derivative can be 0 only when $x^2+2x-24=0$, which by completing the square is when $$(x+1)^2-25 = ((x+1)-5)((x+1)+5)=0$$

In other words $\cases{x_1 = -6\\x_2 = 4}$

Now it is enough to see that we have positive coefficient for $x^2$ to conclude that negative derivative is between the roots. This means the first one must be a maximum and the second a minimum.

What remains is to evaluate the integral in these two points, if you need to find the function value there, that is.